# A kind of thread pool

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, threadpool

I used to call CreateThread() for all my threads, and WaitForMultipleObjects(), an leave the routine.

To get somewhat faster code, I'd like to do a kind of thread pool. My thread pools are sometimes created, later used multiple times, and later destroyed (ie., there is not a single pool created at the begining of the program). Each thread in my thread pool call the same routine with different parameters, the number of threads is constant, and they always need to be launched at the same time.

What I do is as follows :

```
DWORD WINAPI runFunction(LPVOID p) {
   Thread* = (Thread*) p;
    while(true) {
      WaitForSingleObject(thread->awakeEvenHandle, INFINITE);
      thread->run();
      SetEvent(thread->SleepingEventHandle);
      SuspendThread(thread->handle);
    }
    return 0;
 }


void ExecuteThreads(std::vector<Thread*> &threads) {
  HANDLE* waitingEvents = new HANDLE[threads.size()];
  for (int i=0; i<threads.size(); i++) {
      if (threads[i]->handle == NULL) {
        threads[i]->AwakeEventHandle = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, "Awake");
        threads[i]->SleepingEventHandle = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, "Sleeping");
        threads[i]->handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0. runFunction, (void*) threads[i], CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
       }
       ResumeThread(threads[i]->handle);
       ResetEvent(threads[i]->SleepingEventHandle);
       SetEvent(threads[i]->AwakeEventHandle);
       waitingEvents[i] = threads[i]->SleepingEventHandle;
   }
   WaitForMultipleObjects( threads.size(), waitingEvents, TRUE, INFINITE);
}
```

My class Thread has a destructor which calls CloseHandle for the HANDLEs SleepingEventHandle and AwakeEventHandle, and for the thread handle.  The function Thread::run() is pure virtual, and it's up to the coder to inherit the Thread for an actual run() implementation.

As it, the code doesn't work . One reason is that when I don't need this pool anymore, the destructors of the Threads are called, but the runFunction cannot exits and this crashes (the pointer "thread" has been destroyed but is still used the the function). There are probably many other problems with my code.

How would you do it, in a simple manner ? Is-there an easy fix ? What problems will I encounter with this code ?

Thanks!

Comment: You've already touched on the issue.  The `run()` function can block, so you need a way to interrupt it that all classes that implement it will respect.

Comment: Try and have a look to use the windows implementation of thread pool. It will simplify things. Here are some good articles from msdn magazine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=KennyKerr&sdmi=authors

Comment: Why don't you just use the operating system support available instead of spinning your own? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I read a little bit more on Windows Thread Pool and there indeed seems to be interesting functions... thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to deal with such low level api functions? Have a look at [`boost::thread` and `boost::thread_group`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html). Also there is a [thread pool implementation](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) works with `boost::thread`.

Now if your threads work for a short period of time, your system will have remarkable overhead with creating and signaling all those threads and events. [ppl Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx) or [tbb::task](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00166.html) are definitely the ways to go.